# String concatenation returning undefined on Jest test snapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have the following react component

```
import styles from './Alert.module.scss';

const Alert = ({
  role = 'document',
  type = 'info',
}) => (
<GridItem>
  <div className={`${styles.alert} ${styles[`alert-${type}`]}`} role={role}>
   {icon && <div className={`${styles['alert-icon']}`} />}
   <div className={styles.content}>{children}</div>
  </div>
</GridItem>
```

and I am writing my tests like this

```
jest.mock('./Alert.module.scss', () => ({ 
  'alert': 'alert', 
  'type': 'info',
}));

jest.mock('./GridItem', () => 'GridItem');

describe('Alert', () => {
  it('should render correctly', () => {
    expect(renderer.create(<Alert>Alert</Alert>)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Problem is when it is creating the snapshot, the type variable is returning undefined. I assume it has something to do with the string concatenation, because the "role" variable is writing correctly.

here is the snapshot.

```
<GridItem>
  <div
    className="alert undefined"
    role="document"
  >
    <div>
      Alert
    </div>
  </div>
</GridItem>
`;
```

So, I am not sure what I am missing here or if there's any kinda of limitation regarding to the string concat.
How can I get it correctly ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're prefixing the `type` variable with `alert-`, and it seems not to be present on the mocked `styles` object. So you can try adding it

```js
jest.mock('./Alert.module.scss', () => ({ 
  'alert': 'alert', 
  'type': 'info',

  // add the following line
  'alert-info': 'info'
}));
```

Comment: It worked. It seems obvious to me but apparently I am wrong but is there a reason it not concatenate the string with the variable passed on the test ? obs: will mark you answer as correct in 3 minutes when it allows me to.

Comment: Which variable "passed on the test" do you refer to?

Comment: the "type" variable.

Comment: if you render the component with different type property `renderer.create(<Alert type="warning">Alert</Alert>)`, then you can expect `styles['alert-warning']` to be used instead